# Kibana interface with ELK on virtual host

Tags: nginx, elasticsearch, kibana, ubuntu-server, vmware-player

I use [this tutorial](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-use-logstash-and-kibana-to-centralize-and-visualize-logs-on-ubuntu-14-04) to install ELK (Elasticsearch Logstack Kibana) to analyse logs.

I use to install ELK on a virtual vmware machine running ubuntu server 14.04.
My computer using Windows 7.
Actually I have do this :

- Install Java 7
- Install elascticsearch
- Install kibana
- Install nginx

But now the tuto says :

> Kibana is now accessible via your FQDN or the public IP address of your Logstash Server i.e. http:// logstash_server_public_ip/. If you go there in a web browser, you should see a Kibana welcome page which will allow you to view dashboards but there will be no logs to view because Logstash has not been set up yet. Let's do that now.

But I cannot connect from browser (windows real-machine) to the kibana interface (on linux machine).
I looking a lot on how configure ubuntu server but I'm probably lost.

Thanks to people that stop here to read my bad english!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usually you would point your browser at http://localhost:9200/ to browse Kibana but you need to work out the IP Address of your VM Box.  You can run ifconfig on the ubuntu box to check the IP Address, which you can then hit.  As per:

https://superuser.com/questions/245156/how-can-i-connect-to-a-web-server-running-in-a-vm-when-the-vm-is-in-nat-mode